# using header adds random blank lines in text

Tags: header-footer

Whenever I use headers (even something as simple as including the `fancyhdr` package without setting anything), random blank lines start appearing in my document, seemingly after lines that take up the whole page width. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[left=2in, right=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec, titleps, fancyhdr}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\section{thing} this is an example of a line that is longer than the page width and does not cause any issues
\section{thing 2} this line is close to the page width and creates an extra blank line
\section{thing 3} this line is shorter than the page width
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I were to add a `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`, it looks like this:

[image]

How would I get rid of that extra line between thing 2 and thing 3?

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't load both `titleps` and `fancyhdr` that fight each other firing at the same targets, namely headers and footers.

If you omit `titleps`, the output is as expected:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[left=2in, right=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec, fancyhdr}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\section{thing} this is an example of a line that is longer than the page width and does not cause any issues
\section{thing 2} this line is close to the page width and creates an extra blank line
\section{thing 3} this line is shorter than the page width
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you instead keep `titleps`, you get

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[left=2in, right=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec, titleps}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\section{thing} this is an example of a line that is longer than the page width and does not cause any issues
\section{thing 2} this line is close to the page width and creates an extra blank line
\section{thing 3} this line is shorter than the page width
\end{document}
```

[image]

The header has to be configured, in this case, because `titleps` has different defaults than `fancyhdr`.

In any case, I'd not pack the input as you do: it becomes difficult to read and maintain.

The [analysis made by wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707549/4427) is accurate; however my examples show it *isn't* a LaTeX bug, but a conflict between packages. Anyway, the problem might present itself with the interaction between `titlesec` and `titleps`. If you really like to pack the input like that, add

```
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\par}
```

and the problem will vanish.

Answer (score 2):

You have just created a basis for an example of how adding an extra blank line removes the extra blank line! :-)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[left=2in, right=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec, titleps, fancyhdr}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\section{thing} this is an example of a line that is longer than the page width and does not cause any issues
\section{thing 2} this line is close to the page width and creates an extra blank line

\section{thing 3} this line is shorter than the page width
\end{document}
```

[image]

To tell the truth, adding `\par` at the end of the section gives the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I describe the reason of the problem.

The end of each line in the source file is typically converted to space by TeX's token processor. So, the fragment of code:

```
... end of line
\par
```

is converted to "end" "space" "of" "space" "line" "space" "\par".
More typical, there is empty line instead `\par` and token processor converts empty line to `\par`.

TeX removes the last item item the horizontal line if it is the space when `\par` routines are starting. Then these routines break the horizontal list to the lines of the resulting paragraph. It is normal behavior. So, the space from the end of the paragraph is typically removed.

But in your example, the `\section` macro first inserts `\marks` to the horizontal list and then `\par` is processed after this. So, the horizontal list ends by "space" "marks" and `\par` doesn't remove the last space from the end of line, because the last item in the horizontal list isn't space. The mentioned space is the subject of breaking to the lines now, the paragraph has two lines because the horizontal list is broken at this space. The first line includes all visible material a the second line includes `\marks`.

You can see that this is true. Insert `\tracingall` before the word "line" at the end of the line 12 to your code, i.e.

```
... and creates an extra blank \tracingall line
```

and then look to the log file. You can see at line 142:

```
{the letter l}
{blank space  }
```

This says that a word beginning by `l` is inserted and the blank space (from the end of line) is inserted too. Then you can see at line 2013:

```
{\marks}
```

so the `\marks` is inserted to the horizontal list. Then you can see at line 3210:

```
{\par}
```

and this is the first `{\par}` in the log file. So the `\par` routines are started after inserting `\marks`.

Moreover, you can see that the log file is very confused because LaTeX uses expl3 macros and the full trace of such macros cannot be read. The log says that `\marks` is processed before `\par` and this is LaTeX bug. A correct `\section` macro should process `\par` first and then `\marks` in the vertical mode (or in the next horizontal mode with the title of the section).

Comment: Are you sure this is a LaTeX bug? Isn't `titlesec`/`titleps` most likely the culprit here? Or did you reproduce the bug without those packages?

Comment: hmm how come introducing headers causes this to happen? does having headers cause marks to be processed or something like that? and how come inserting an extra blank line fixes it? (or a `\par`)

Comment: @cfr I see titlessec in tex/latex directory in LeXlive, so it is LaTeX from my point of view.

Comment: @Jeffmagma yes, introducing headers needs inserting `\marks`. And blank line before `\section` runs `\par` before `\section`, so the last space is deleted (see the TeX rule mentioned in my post) before inserting `\marks`.

Comment: @wipet so any error in any document that uses optex is an optex bug???? That's a strange definition. Despite that,  nice analysis of the error.

Comment: You should decide what LaTeX is. If it is LaTeX without packages, then LaTeX alone is almost unusable. If it is LaTeX with packages, then this issue demonstrates the LaTeX bug.